# Kafka connect: What is the default acks value used by kafka connect?

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

We are using debezium source connector. What is the default acks value[1,0,all] while producing messages to kafka?

Config for producer - https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/configuration/producer-configs.html#acks

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the Kafka Connect worker log you can see the setting that's in use. Here's a sample from a Debezium connector that I'm running, showing that it's set to `1`:

```
[2020-07-03 09:11:39,715] INFO [SOURCE_MYSQL_01|task-0] ProducerConfig values:
        acks = 1
        …
```

Comment: I am not able to find this in my worker logs. I will try setting the log level to info.
As per the code the acks value is set to all by default https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/caa806cd82fb9fa88510c81de53e69ac9846311d/connect/runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/runtime/Worker.java#L665

Comment: Would you share how did you set acks=1 as it's by default to all.